# Triangulate modifier doesn't work properly after combining faces

Tags: modeling, modifiers, faces

After I combine two faces into one and then apply the triangulate modifier, it treats the newly created face as two faces instead of one, so it divides the face into two triangles. Is there a way to fix this and make it two combined faces as one?

Triangulate modifier applied to two separate faces:

[image: Triangulate modifier applied to two separate faces]

Triangulate modifier applied to a combined face

[image: Triangulate modifier applied to a combined face]

Comment: could you please make some screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you still have one or two vertices that make that face triangulate twice?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Press [tab] to go edit mode.
2. Press [A] to select all vertices.
3. Press [T] to open the tools panel on left side
4. Scroll down and click on [remove doubles]
5. press [P] separate by loose parts (this will clean up the vertices loose)
6. then go back to object mode [tab], and select the corrected mesh.
7. [ctrl]+[i] to select inverse
8. [x] to delete the garbage vertex.
9. select back the mesh [tab] edit mode.

10 [A] to select all your faces in this case.

11 finally what you're looking for. [Alt]+[P] mesh poke to triangulate.